On the $(\infty,n)$ Day convolution and monoidal Yoneda embedding
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a monoidal category.  In ordinary category theory, the Day convolution gives monoidal structure on the category of presheaves $Psh(C)=Func(C^{op},\mathbf{Set})$ such that the Yoneda embedding $y:C\to Psh(C)$ is a monoidal functor.  This works also for ordinary enriched categories.
This should have an obvious analog in $(\infty,n)$ categories.  Now let $\mathcal{C}$ be an $E_k$-monoidal $(\infty,n)$-category.  Then $Psh(\mathcal{C})=Func_{(\infty,n)}(\mathcal{C}^{op},\mathbf{Cat}_{(\infty,n-1)})$ should inherit an $E_k$-monoidal structure such that the Yoneda embedding $y:\mathcal{C}\to Psh(\mathcal{C})$ is an $E_k$-monoidal $(\infty,n)$ functor.
How should one go about obtaining this result in $(\infty,n)$-categories?
Lurie's Higher algebra, section 2.2.6, gives a version of this result of $(\infty,1)$ categories.  If $\mathcal{C}$ is a (suitably small) $E_k$-monoidal $(\infty,1)$-category, then construction 2.2.6.7 and proposition 2.2.6.16 give an $E_k$-monoidal $(\infty,1)$ category $Fun^{E_k}(\mathcal{C},\textbf{Cat}_{(\infty,0)})^{\otimes}$ whose underlying $\infty$-category is $Fun(\mathcal{C},\textbf{Cat}_{(\infty,0)})$.
From what I understand, the fact that the Day convolution in ordinary category theory makes the Yoneda embedding a monoidal functor is proven via the coend formula.  I do not immediately see from the contents of section 2.2.6 why the Yoneda embedding is monoidal in the $(\infty,1)$ setting.  Is this also obvious? Maybe from 2.2.6.12 somehow?  Glasman also proves a version, and also proves that the Yoneda embedding is monoidal, but this seems to be more involved and perhaps harder to generalize.
I can see two reasonable routes for the $(\infty,n)$ setting:
One could then try to extend these results to enriched $(\infty,1)$ categories, in the language of Gepner and Haugseng.  A version of Yoneda lemma for this setting is proven by Hinich.
Second, a fibrational version of the Yoneda lemma is given by Rasekh for $\mathcal{D}$-simplicial spaces, which in particular covers n-fold complete Segal spaces.  One could then try to give this generalization completely in fibrational language, by constructing a monoidal structure on the $(\infty,n)$-category ${Cart_{(\infty,n-1)}}_{/\mathcal{C}}$ of cartesian fibrations over $\mathcal{C}$ (which, via a Grothendieck construction, is equivalent to $Psh(\mathcal{C})$.
Thirdly, I suppose one could also try to replicate the coend definition using $(\infty,n)$-colimits, but I would assume there is a reason it is not done this way in $(\infty,1)$.
Unfortunately, my use for this construction is motivated by physics and representation theory, so I am very new to working with the formal aspects of $(\infty,n)$ categories.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I think I didn't understand, why not use Hinich's enriched Yoneda embedding?

A version of the Yoneda embedding (such as Hinich's) gives, for an $(\infty,n)$-category $\mathcal{C}$, a fully-faithful functor $y:\mathcal{C}\to Psh(\mathcal{C})$.  Then there are two things to check.  First, if $\mathcal{C}$ is $E_k$ monoidal, then $Psh(\mathcal{C})$ is naturally $E_k$ monoidal.  Second, that the Yoneda embedding $y$ is an $E_k$ monoidal functor.

Ah, this is done in Hinich's follow up paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.09538

Oh and if I am not mistaken also in https://arxiv.org/abs/2406.08925 (see under Corollary 1.7)

Thank you so much for this, these appear to be exactly what I was looking for!
